# Cytoscape Graph not working until page scroll

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm currently working on implementing a cytoscape.js graph on a website, and I'm having a weird bug that I haven't been able to pin down.

My page includes several tabs of information (using the tab-pane class), and the graph in question is on a hidden tab until the user clicks on its section to make the tab "active" and the elements display set to block instead of none.

With just having it like this, the bug I get is that the graph fails to render on the screen at all when it starts as `display:none`, and then changed to block later. I have the correct sized window, the pan-tools I use with it render, but the graph itself will not render, even on calling `fit()` with the pan-tool interface.

Since the graph will work if it is originally set to be on the page, my tweak to get around this has been to set its display on, but make its visibility hidden until you click on the right tab.

This works to *some* extent, but it has problems with it. Since it's hidden, it still technically takes up space on the page when you load, leading to double the whitespace at the bottom of the "content" section where the tabs display.

More importantly, this method doesn't seem to be foolproof either, because while the graph will always load, sometimes (can't pinpoint the exact case) it will be unclickable / uninteractable, where clicking the nodes doesn't do anything. As soon as I scroll the page or resize it though, suddenly it'll work.

I had tried to solve this with a hack, where I would force the page to scroll down and up barely without it visually noticeable, but that doesn't seem to work either.

The first thing I'd like to figure out is how to fix this last issue, and then secondly figure out a better method to get around the `display: none` issue above if possible.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307570/a-hidden-cytoscape-graph-cannot-be-displayed-later  Same answer applies.

Comment: Missed that, thank you